# Call a macro if a specific range of external links change

Tags: excel, vba, events, range, worksheet

I have information updating to a table in my sheet occasionally due to external links. I need to copy the last line in my table over to another table when that specific row (the last row) has a calculation change.

I use the Worksheet_Calculate to scan and see if there was any calculation change within the whole sheet, but need to specify range. The code is shown below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim rWatchRange As Range
    Set rWatchRange = Range("A10:K10")
        If Not Application.Intersect(target, rWatchRange) Is Nothing Then
            Call Update
        End If
End Sub
```

I'm getting a Compile Error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name.

`Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal target As Range)`

Could someone please help explain to me how to fix this issue?

Comment: What is `target` supposed to be?

Comment: My bad I updated the code to what it was when I was using the target value.

Comment: `Worksheet_Calculate` does not have any arguments. You cannot just add arguments to the built-in events. Delete `ByVal target As Range` and then fix the code to not use `target` first.

Comment: I was able to figure out another way to make my code work without using the above code. Thank you for your help.